# TortoiseSVN: Unable to connect to repository at URL 'svn://servername/projectname'

Tags: tortoisesvn

We usually check-out our projects through 'svn://servername/projectname/trunk' (Repo-browser). 
Our current server is Windows Server 2008 Standard installed with TortoiseSVN 32bit 1.8.1 2013/07/22 version.
We have no problem in accessing our repositories from said server.

*transfer all our repositories and projects in a new server..

When trying to set-up a new server which is Windows Server 2012 R2 installed with TortoiseSVN 64bit 1.9.7 2017/08/08 version, we can't check-out our projects through svn://...

Upon trying to check repo-browser or checkout using 'svn://newservername/projectname/trunk'.. below error occur.

Checkout Failed!
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://newservername/projectname/trunk'
Can't connect to host 'newservername': No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Should we coordinate with our Network and Server incharge/s on possible required authorizations etc.? What area can we advise them to check? Or is there anything we still need to set in TortoiseSVN?

Your respond is very much appreciated.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run [svnserve](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.intro.whatis.html#svn.intro.components) in the background in order to use the `svn:` protocol. TortoiseSVN itself is just a Subversion client and only provides repository access through serverless `file:` protocol.

Luckily, for a few years now the TortoiseSVN installer has been bundling the official command-line tools as optional components. Double-check you've installed them in the machine that acts as server:

[image: Modify installation]

[image: Custom setup]

... and then try to figure out the exact mechanism you were using in the old machine to [launch the program as background service](http://jtdan.com/vcs/svn/tortoise/1.6/TortoiseSVN/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html).

Alternatively, you can migrate to a [dedicated server software](https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows) an maybe choose another [network protocol](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html).

Comment: It's now working!. You're a great help! Thanks so much.